# jQuery droppable go right/left

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have this script: http://jsfiddle.net/YuytK/

I need to do something so when you drop it into the left `div`, the black box will stick to the left of the screen, and when you drop it into the right `div`, it will stick to the right of the screen (like left:0 or right:0).

CODE
jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#drag" ).draggable({
        containment: 'body',
        snapTolerance: 100,
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the jQuery UI manual. In your case especially droppable. What you try to do needs both and also some rules what happens in the event of dropping it in a certain zone.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is your friend, read it: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

http://jsfiddle.net/YuytK/1/

```
$(function () {
  $("#drag").draggable({containment: 'body'});
  $("#left").droppable({
      drop: function () {
          $(this).append("<div>Dropped</div>");
          $("#drag").css({left: "0px", right: "auto"});
      }
  });
  $("#right").droppable({
      drop: function () {
          $(this).append("<div>Dropped</div>");
          $("#drag").css({right: "0px", left: "auto"});
      }
  });
});
```